# GA4 Configuration sending browser Title instead of CustomVirtualPageTitle

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, analytics, google-analytics-4

I have followed the steps mentioned in this guide: https://www.analyticsmania.com/post/single-page-web-app-with-google-tag-manager/ to dataLayer.push code whenever a user navigates between pages/states of a website/web application.

I did everything as mentioned inthis guide to send a VirtualPageView using the datalayer.push and created GA4 Event - Page View event that triggers this customVirtual Page.

Also, in the parameters I am sending page_location & page_title for a custom url & title.

However, with the GA4 Tag configuration event is loaded on all pages when container is loaded it sends the browser title. how can I stop GTM from sending the browser title and only get the custom title that we are passing in the platform?

Any help is appreciated here:

Below a screenshot of the events:

[GA4 Tag Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yu7zI.png)

[GA4 PageView Event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkBaZ.png)

Tried everything but need help in the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You did not exactly follow the blog post.

You should add these event parameters in the Google Tag so that they will be sent for every GA4 event.

Here, you only override the `page_location` and the `page_title` for the `page_view` event.

Comment: So what do I need to do then to override the page_location & page_title? I have added page_location & page_title to GA4 Tag and Ga4 event. There are 2 screenshots that I have attached.